# How to deploy SpringBoot Java Maven Web Application to Cloud Run?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-run

**How to deploy SpringBoot Java Maven Web Application to Cloud Run?**

I have tried with the following link https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/java

But in the above tutorials, they specifed about jar file.

Jave 8, SpringBoot 2.3.0.RELEASE versions are using in this project.

Comment: what is the issue with jar file? you can also create jar file and mention the path in docker file

Comment: Change your packaging from war to jar. What's your concern?

Comment: I have tried with two commnads. java -jar target/app.jar
no main manifest attribute, in target/app.jar
-----------------------------------------------
Then i tried with "java -cp app.jar full.package.name.ClassName"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
at com.app.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can successfully deploy springboot application to cloud run using the same tutorial. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/java

Dockerfile configuration for war packages

```
# Use the official maven/Java 8 image to create a build artifact.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/maven
FROM maven:3.8-jdk-11 as builder

# Copy local code to the container image.
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src

# Build a release artifact.
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

# Use AdoptOpenJDK for base image.
# It's important to use OpenJDK 8u191 or above that has container support enabled.
# https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-slim

# Copy the jar to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=builder /app/target/helloworld-*.war/helloworld.war

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/helloworld.war"]
```

I had done it!!!.

***Note***: No need to change the package name from **war** to **jar**.